# Variables not updating correct in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I've been toying with node.js in coffeescript to pull some stories from reddit.com's json interface but running in to some snags.

I want to parse json from `http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json` and then append a query statement with the parameters `count` and `after` and reparse. Repeat based on arguments passed to `get_stories()`

When I run the code below as `file.js > test.txt` I get unexpected results. (See below) It looks like `querystring.count` is being updated but they all match what urls in the last pass would look like. Not sure why I'm not seeing count=0,25,50,75,125. Also, `querystring.after` is not present on the urls. What is going on?

Code:

```
# Requires
request = require 'request'
qs = require 'querystring'
mongojs = require 'mongojs'

# Connect to db
db = mongojs 'mongodb://localhost/feedtraining', ['subreddit_stories']

get_stories = (subreddit, {per_page, pages}, storyCallback) ->
    current_page = 0
    querystring = {}

    while true
        querystring.count = current_page * per_page

        request_uri = "http://www.reddit.com/r/#{subreddit}/.json?#{qs.stringify querystring}"

        request
            uri: request_uri,
            json: true,
            (error, response, body) ->
                if !error and response.statusCode == 200
                    for item in body.data.children
                        if item.data.selftext_html is null
                            storyCallback request_uri, current_page, item.data

                    querystring.after = body.data.children[body.data.children.length-1].id
                else
                    console.log error

                return

        if current_page == pages then break else current_page++

    return

get_stories 'programming', {per_page: 25, pages: 5}, (request_uri, page, story) ->
    db.subreddit_stories.insert(story)
    console.log request_uri
```

Output:

```
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/.json?count=125
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Edit*]

If you need to chain asynchronous actions, like setting `querystring.after` for the next `request`, you won't be able to use `while`. The loop will run to completion, starting all of the `request`s before any of them finish and `querystring.after` can be set.

You can rewrite the iteration with `function`s as *continuations* so each request will wait until `after` is available from the previous request.

Side note: Since `after` should already move the start of the collection, you'll probably want to keep `count` the same value. Otherwise, the size of the collection will grow with each request.

```
get_stories = (subreddit, {per_page, pages}, storyCallback) ->
    current_page = 0

    send_next_request = (querystring = {}) ->
        querystring.count = per_page

        request_uri = "http://www.reddit.com/r/#{subreddit}/.json?#{qs.stringify querystring}"

        request
            uri: request_uri,
            json: true,
            (error, response, body) ->
                if !error and response.statusCode == 200
                    for item in body.data.children
                        if item.data.selftext_html is null
                            storyCallback request_uri, current_page, item.data

                    current_page++
                    if current_page < pages
                        send_next_request(after: body.data.children[body.data.children.length-1].id)

    send_next_request()
```

---

[*Original*]

You need to create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) around `request_uri`.

```
request_uri = "http://www.reddit.com/r/#{subreddit}/.json?#{qs.stringify querystring}"

do (request_uri) ->
  request
    url: request_uri,
    # ...
```

JavaScript, and in turn CoffeeScript, doesn't ([yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)) have block scoping, so only 1 `request_uri` is created for the entire loop and can only keep 1 value.

Adding in that `request` is asynchronous, the `while true` loop will run to completion before:

```
storyCallback request_uri, current_page, item.data
```

is evaluated for any requests. And, `request_uri` by this point will always have the last value it was given in the loop.

The closure creates an additional `function` scope so each iteration of `while true` can have its own `request_uri`.

---

This is documented under [Loops and Comprehensions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.
>
> ```
> for filename in list
>   do (filename) ->
>     fs.readFile filename, (err, contents) ->
>       compile filename, contents.toString()
> ```

Comment: That works great for the uri! Any insight on why the `after` parameter isn't showing up on any of the uris? Also because of the async nature of the code. Any way to get it to work?

Comment: @Kylee That's because the `while` loop is already done and has started all of the `request`s before any have finished to set `querystring.after`. See my edit for more.

Comment: That worked! I knew the async was causing a lot of these issues but didn't know how to fix them. So used to python on the server side, javascript on the client side.

Comment: @Kylee You might also consider using a "*control flow*" library such as [`async`](https://npmjs.org/package/async), which includes an asynchronous `while` as `async.whilst()`.